# react native fetch request to localhost server, even after change to IPV4

Tags: react-native, fetch

I'm trying to make http request in my react native app(in android in real device) with the localhost url.
after it failed in localhost url with the error

> Network request Failed

I changed it to my ipv4 but it still not works.
but when I'm using in POSTMAN to check with my ipv4 it looks it works fine.

```
 try {
            let response = await fetch("http://myIPV4address:3008", {
                method: method,
                headers: headers,
                body: body != null ? JSON.stringify(body) : null,
            })
            console.log('response:',response)
            const endTime = (new Date()).getTime();
            if( response.status == 401 ) {
                return Promise.reject(response);
            }
            if( response.status == 400 ) {
                return Promise.reject(response);
            }
            if( response.status == 404 ) {
                return Promise.reject(response);
            }
            if( response.status == 500 ) {
                return Promise.reject(response);
            }
            if( response.status == 502 ) {
                return Promise.reject(response);
            }
            let responseJson = response.headers.map['content-type'][0].includes('application/json') ? await response.json() : response.statusText;
            return responseJson;
        } catch(error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
```

maybe it is settings in react native app I need to change?

Comment: Are you using a real device?

Comment: yes. in my smartphone xiaomi mi max 2

Comment: What error exactly you are getting?

Comment: Network request Failed

Comment: Is your android device on the same network as your localhost?

Comment: I solved my issue by connect to wifi where to pc is connect

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
I connected to the wifi where the pc is connect because before it doesn't know what is localhost is

Answer (score 0):

look for dns server the solution is to configure your emulator